# JavaScript function to compare values in the array and return it

Tags: javascript, typescript, underscore.js

Mods: feel free to paraphrase the question.
What I am trying to do is tell whether all values in the array for a given **dynamic** property are the same and, if **true**, return it.

I have achieved this in 3 lines using underscore.js, however, I was hoping this could be simplified/shortened:

```
var val = this.children[0]["myProperty"];
var same = _.all(this.children, child => child["myProperty"] === val);

return same ? val : null;
```

so that if:

`this.children = [{"myProperty":null},{"myProperty":2},{"myProperty":1},{"myProperty":1}];`  ...returns `null`

`this.children = [{"myProperty":1},{"myProperty":1},{"myProperty":1},{"myProperty":1}];` ...returns `1`

N.B. the value of "myProperty" is a **single digit whole number or null**

Comment: You could shave off a few characters by using `.myProperty` instead of `["myProperty"]`, unless `myProperty` is the value of a variable.

Comment: yes, it's a dynamic property. i was hoping for some sorta combination of `all` and `filter` function - a one-liner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a dynamic property:

```
var prop = "myProperty";

//vanilla JS
return this.children.map(o => o[prop]).reduce((acc, v) => acc === v? v: null);  

//and underscore
return _.reduce(_.pluck(this.children, prop), (acc, v) => acc === v? v: null);
```

Comment: very nice! which one should i pick? =)

Comment: Doesn't really matter they're basically the same. If you already use underscore, stay consistent. if you don't, you don't have to include it just to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, using vanilla javascript and `reduce`, or maybe it will push you in the right direction:

```
function children(arr,prop){
  return arr.reduce(
    function(prevVal,curVal){
      return prevVal == curVal[prop] ? prevVal : null
    },
    arr[0][prop]
  );
}

children([{"myProperty":null},{"myProperty":2},{"myProperty":1},{"myProperty":1}],'myProperty')
> null
children([{"myProperty":1},{"myProperty":1},{"myProperty":1},{"myProperty":1}],'myProperty')
> 1
```

or

```
Array.prototype.children = function(prop){
  return this.reduce(
    function(prevVal,curVal){
      return prevVal == curVal[prop] ? prevVal : null
    },
    this[0][prop]
  );
}

[{"myProperty":null},{"myProperty":2},{"myProperty":1},{"myProperty":1}].children('myProperty')
> null
[{"myProperty":1},{"myProperty":1},{"myProperty":1},{"myProperty":1}].children('myProperty')
> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your own solution returns negative result asap. It's still O(n), but if `children` is huge and values are rarely equal, difference can be sensible (almost never). In vanilla JS, using [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
function childrenValue(prop) {
    var first = this.children[0][prop];

    return this.children.every(child => child[prop] === first) ? first : null;
}
```